# How to develop an email client app using react native

Tags: android, react-native, android-studio, email

I want to build an email client app using react-native. I found some posts related to this [Developing an email client app on android](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8009351/developing-an-email-client-app-on-android). Hontvári Levente posted answer here to use PopMailImporter.java. I found a similar solution in react native. It is to use Linker, but it is not a 'client app'. I have two questions:
 Are there any solutions to build email client apps using react native?
 What is the best (popular) solution to build email client apps using android studio?

Comment: I am also interested

Answer (score 2, accepted):

you can make email clients in react native by using [react-native-mailcore](https://www.npmjs.com/package/react-native-mailcore) package.

and I think best popular email client is [k9mail](https://k9mail.app/documentation/) library ([git](https://github.com/k9mail/k-9))